# Windows 7 system32 different contents depending on how its viewed

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, telnet, directory

Using Windows 7 x64 Enterprise. When I view C:\windows\System32 through explorer I can see telnet.exe, if I open cmd from the start menu I can use telnet. If I open C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe via Launchy (as admin or not) I can't use telnet or even see telnet after running

Running from start menu

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir telnet*
07/13/2009  05:39 PM            79,872 telnet.exe
           1 File(s)         79,872 bytes
```

Running from Launchy

```
C:\Windows\System32>dir telnet*
           File Not Found
```

Anyone know why the contents of the folder change depending on how it is viewed?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same cmd, and not  the 64 bit version fromone place and the 32 bit from the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zoredache said, you may be using two different versions of command prompt.

Windows 7 x64 has something called WOW64 which allows 32 bit applications to run on the 64 bit OS in compatibility mode.

I suppose Launchy is a 32 bit application. (Open task Manager and in processes tab see if Launchy's process is shown as Launchy.exe*32. If yes it is running under WOW64)

Windows transparently replaces System32 for 32 bit applications with C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder. This is a folder with 32 bit variants of common windows applications like cmd and regedit present in system32. Telnet may not be present in SysWOW64. Hence the issue you are facing.

Comment: That is the problem, I don't like that they both say system32 when one isn't system32. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem! Note than in Windows 10, "*32" is missing, so will you need to enable the "Platform" column to see if a program is 32 bit, see https://superuser.com/a/1321393/253137